# How to structure a React Context for posts that have comments

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

### Introduction

In am implementing an Instagram clone:

1. Users have posts.
2. Posts can be liked.
3. Users can comment in posts.
4. Posts have a totalLikes and totalComments field.
5. Comments can be liked.
6. Users can reply to comments.
7. Comments have a totalLikes and totalComments (replies) field.

Until now, I have been working with the current PostsContext:

```
const initialState = {};

export function PostsProvider({ children }) {
   const [contents, dispatch] = useReducer(contentsReducer, initialState);

   const addUserPosts = (userId, posts, unshift = false, cached = true) => { ... }

   const likePost = (postOwnerId, postId) => { ... }

   const commentPost = (postOwnerId, postId, comment) => { ... }

   const getUserPosts = (userId) => { ... }

   const getUserPost = (userId, postId) => { ... } 
}
```

Where, my stateful data looks like:

```
{
   userId1: { 
      posts: [ 
         {
            id,
            uri,
            totalLikes,
            totalComments,
            isLiked,
            date
         },
         ...
      ]
   },
   userId2: { posts: [...] }
 }
```

### Question

My question is, should I use another context for comments? I mean, comments will work the same way as posts, they can be liked and replied... so maybe, it is unnecessary.

When a user comments in a post:

```
1. The post totalComments is increased.
2. If the user is replying to a comment in the post, the replied comment's totalComments is increased too.
```

When a user likes a comment, it doesn't affect to the post "data" itself, only to the liked comment totalLikes field.

So... if I create a new context for comments, it seems that I will need to consume the PostsContext inside it, in order to increase the post totalComments field.

Any ideas about how to structure my posts context?

Note: My question is more about the context organization than anything else (do not look at implementation, just to the structure of my stateful data and the idea of splitting contexts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are trade-offs. With multiple contexts you have the option of having a component rendered within a single context, thus reducing refreshes (increasing performance) when another context changes.

However, if most of your components need access to multiple contexts, it may work better to have a "store" (single app-level context). If you're using the [selector pattern](https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors#calculating-derived-data-with-selectors) (which is not just for Redux), then a selector can compute data that would otherwise be in multiple contexts.

I am working on a project with multiple contexts, and regularly think about combining them.

If your project is complex, you may want to consider [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) instead of contexts. It adds complexity but solves some of the issues around organization and combining different areas of the state. If you do that I highly recommend starting with [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: But there is a small inflection point: if I consume the context of comments within the post provider, it would be like using some kind of data denormalization to simplify the code, rather than for optimization, since when consuming the context of posts, every time the comments context changes, would also extra re-render my components.

Comment: If I do not do it like this, and I consume the two contexts in the comments section, independently, it would be like having the logic of the action of commenting "separated" in two parts (one for increasing the number of comments of a post in the posts context + another for storing the comment (and increasing the number of responses of the possible answered comment) in the comments context), which, from my point of view, is a bit weird.

Comment: Anyways, I think that I will try to create two contexts, ignoring that small logic decouple, as it will be easier to work with the data structures.